# Were Ferdinand and Isabella the most important royal couple?

Tags: spain, monarchy, royalty, kingdom

Ferdinand and Isabella ruled Aragon and Castile jointly from 1474 to 1504, a thirty-year period during which the modern country of Spain was born, ships they commissioned discovered and explored the New World, and the Spanish Empire was formed in the Western Hemisphere. Spain achieved its peak during the reigns of their next two successors (Charles and Phillip), who largely preserved and built upon the policies and institutions they founded. Each of them was already a monarch when they married, and during their marriage, they shared power over both kingdoms. In other words, it was not an instance of one person wearing the crown and the other merely being the spouse/consort. (One could argue over whether their powers were equal, but that's an argument for a different question. The fact is, they both had royal power.)

I want to fairly and accurately state Ferdinand and Isabella's importance relative to other royal couples. My question is, would it be correct to state that they were the most important royal *couple* in world history? In European history? In medieval European history? Or if "important" doesn't work, what about another adjective that does (successful, famous, influential, etc.)?

Just to stress the point, I'm uninterested in comparisons with royal couples where only one member was actually a monarch (regardless of how much behind-the-scenes influence his/her spouse is believe to have had).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleanor_of_Aquitaine Duchess, not Queen, but married to 2 different Kings; Important on the convoluted history of french fiefs owned/claimed by England (lead to the 100y war).

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/biography/Isabella-II-queen-of-Jerusalem  when very young, married  Emperor Frederick II, who claimed her authority to himself (besides consummating the marriage ahead of time). Died giving birth. Sad short life. Ferdinand/Isabella set a high bar to compare.

Comment: Can you revise to avoid bad subjective?  To make an authoritative answer possible?

Comment: The importance of a royal couple can be argued with facts, examples, and logic. Knowledgeable people ought to be able to reach a consensus on whether there are other good contenders for the distinction, who they are, and why. Or perhaps there are one or more royal couples who blow them out of the water and I was an idiot for not remembering. So yes, It is a subjective question, but how is it "bad"? It's not like asking which is the best Beatles song or the most delicious flavor of pie.

Comment: Your last requirement sends this into No True Scotsman twrritory.

Comment: @davo  Your question contains a historical error. "Each of them was already a monarch when they married,"  Ferdinand and Isabella married on 19 October 1469.  Isabeela becamenQueen of castile, etc. 11 December 1474. Ferdinand became King of Aragon etc. 20 January 1479.  They were not already monarchs when married.  You wrote something which you did not know to be true.  Don't do that again.

Comment: @MAGolding They were crown prince and crown princess when they married and had a prenuptial agreement that they would share power when they inherited their crowns. My point was that they both brought royal power into the marriage independently and it was shared from Day 1. Please forgive my imprecision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jadwiga_of_Poland

This one is comparable to Ferdinand and Isabella. The Queen of Poland married the King of Lithuania, which sealed the conversion of the king and of Lithuania itself to Catholicism from paganism (thus ending the pagan raids on Christians and the Baltic crusades), and the formation of the PLC, one of the largest countries in Europe for a long time afterwards.

Ferdinand/Isabella set a high bar to compare others, but just to cite other cases, probably farther from the mark:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleanor_of_Aquitaine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleanor_of_Aquitaine)

Duchess, not Queen, but her duchy was important, and she married to 2 different Kings (France and England); Important on the convoluted history of french fiefs owned/claimed by England (which lead to the Hundred Years war). She had authority at least during parts of her complex life, she even may have revolted against her husband with her sons.

[britannica.com/biography/Isabella-II-queen-of-Jerusalem](http://britannica.com/biography/Isabella-II-queen-of-Jerusalem)

when very young, married Emperor Frederick II, who claimed her authority to himself (besides consummating the marriage ahead of time and maybe also raping her cousin-companion who traveled with her). Died giving birth, after a sad short life. Her importance was involving her husband with the crusades. And, this case is Queen+Emperor, not Queen+King.

Answer (score -1):

The rule of William III and Mary II of England started the modern period in the history of this country. William could claim the English throne because we was married to Mary, the daughter of James II. And they came to power as the result og the so-called [Glorious revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution). England became a true constitutional monarchy, as it is now, as a result of this revolution.

Comment: Not comparable. William and Mary were offered the throne *jointly* as a sop to succession /primogeniture laws - Mary was James' II eldest daughter, William merely a nephew. **But** all executive power was vested in William: firstly, because William would not have accepted any other terms, and, secondly, Mary, as a dutiful Protestant wife, was genuinely shocked at the idea of outranking her husband, an arrangement she thought contrary to God's law of the man being the 'head' of the woman. They both **reigned**: William **ruled**.

Comment: Before they were offered throne, they had to invade England with huge force:-)

Comment: Only after William had been invited by members of the elite! And William - supported by his wife, whose claim to the throne was better - made it clear he would not be a mere consort to Queen Mary.

Comment: PS William invaded. Mary didn't.